# Using reduce and lambda expression to find sum of square roots

Tags: python, lambda

I've been learning about higher-order functions and wanted to write a function that applies a function to a stepped range of numbers. 
In this case, it should return the sum of every second square root between 0 and 100.

```
def sum(lower, upper, step = 1, func = lambda *x: x):
    return reduce(func, range(lower, upper + 1, step))

sum(0, 100, 2, math.sqrt)

TypeError: sqrt() takes exactly one argument (2 given)
```

Would appreciate any pointers!

Comment: You've been downvoted for your question; in order to improve it, I'd suggest:
1) You should not name a function sum, as that is a builtin
2) You should read the manual on what reduce does (hint: pretty sure Brionius also needs to do so if in his answer is using your version of sum instead of the builtin)

Comment: Sorry about the naming! It seems I had an erroneous understanding of the reduce function, thank you.

I believe I included the desired behavior, is there anything I can add to potential future questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be assuming that `reduce` will automatically add elements of the list after applying `sort` to each element. That is, you seem to think `reduce` works like this:

```
def reduce(func, lst, start):
    return sum(map(func, lst), start)
```

As written, you need to pass a function to your `sum` that both applies `math.sqrt` to a single list value *and* adds that result to the current total.

```
sum(0, 100, 2, lambda x, y: x + math.sqrt(y))
```

The easiest thing to do is use the body of my pseudo-reduce above:

```
def sum_of_sqroots(lower, upper, step=1, func=lambda x: x):
    return sum(map(func, range(lower, upper+1, step))
```

`reduce` is rarely needed (and in Python 3 was "demoted" from the built-in namespace to the `functools` module) outside of functional languages, as it is usually clearer to write an explicity loop that maintains an accumulator.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Python 3. Lets code this up normally:

```
result = 0
for i in range(0, 100, 2):
    result += math.sqrt(i)
print(result)
```

Lets work from here to what you're looking for. First, lets replace the `for` loop with a `map` and a `sum`.

```
result = sum(map(math.sqrt, range(0, 100, 2)))
print(result)
```

Now, we'll put that in a function.

```
def sum_of_the_square_roots_from_0_to_100_with_step_2():
    return sum(map(math.sqrt, range(0, 100, 2)))
print(sum_of_the_square_roots_from_0_to_100_with_step_2())
```

Lets parametrise the function.

```
def sum_of_func_from_0_to_100_with_step_2(func):
    return sum(map(func, range(0, 100, 2)))
print(sum_of_func_from_0_to_100_with_step_2)
```

And parametrise the range.

```
def sum_of_func_over_range(func, *range_args):
    return sum(map(func, range(*range_args)))
print(sum_of_func_over_range(math.sqrt, 0, 100, 2))
```

There you have it! Pass any function (well, callable of at least one argument) and a range spec.

Comment: Thank you! I like the idea of writing workable code then parametrizing and refactoring to more elegant solution.